# $.post vs $.ajax

Tags: asp.net, ajax, jquery, asp.net-ajax

I'm trying to use the $.post method to call a web service, I've got it working using the $.ajax method:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "StandardBag.aspx/RemoveProductFromStandardBag",
    data: "{'standardBagProductId': '" + standardBagProductId.trim() + "' }",
    success: function(){
                 $((".reload")).click();
             },
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json"
});
```

But when I move the same method into the $.post method, it will not work:

```
$.post("StandardBag.aspx/RemoveProductFromStandardBag",
    "{'standardBagProductId': '" + standardBagProductId.trim() + "' }",
    function () { $((".reload")).click(); },
    "json"
);
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It doesn't work because in your `$.post` method you cannot set the content type of the request to `application/json`. So it is not possible to invoke an ASP.NET PageMethod using `$.post` because an ASP.NET PageMethod requires a JSON request. You will have to use `$.ajax`.

I would just modify the `data` in order to ensure that it is properly JSON encoded:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "StandardBag.aspx/RemoveProductFromStandardBag",
    data: JSON.stringify({ standardBagProductId: standardBagProductId.trim() }),
    success: function() {
        $(".reload").click();
    },
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json"
});
```

Comment: I recently ran into this exact same issue, this was the correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is another way to do it not using ajax. It uses post  and returns a json object.

```
data = {};
data.standardBagProductId = standardBagProductId.trim();
$.post("StandardBag.aspx/RemoveProductFromStandardBag", data , function(response){
    $(".reload").click();
},"json");
```

Comment: briefly describe what the code you are posting does.

Comment: You should add the description to the answer.

Answer (score -1):

for $.post function second param should not be in "".

```
$.post("StandardBag.aspx/RemoveProductFromStandardBag",
    {'standardBagProductId': standardBagProductId.trim() },
    function () { $(".reload").click(); },
    "json"
);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try changing your post data like this,

```
 {standardBagProductId: standardBagProductId.trim() }
```