# Difference between $.post and $.ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, serialization

Curious if anyone knows what the difference is in regards to the data parameter.

I have a `$.post` method that takes a `$('#myform').serialize()` as my data param and works.

If I try the same using the `$.ajax()` approach, it doesn't work as my data param doesn't appear correct.

Does anyone know the difference and what I might use instead of the above `.serialize`?

Comment: similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7528757/post-vs-ajax

Answer (score 28, accepted):

After re-reading some online documentation, I decided to stick with $.post over $.ajax.

The $.ajax method's data param does something different than the $.post method does, not sure what exactly, but there is a difference.

The only reason I wanted to use $.ajax is because I wanted to be able to handle events and didn't realize I could do so with $.post.

Here is what I ended up with

```
function GetSearchItems() {
    var url = '@Url.Action("GetShopSearchResults", "Shop", New With {.area = "Shop"})';
    var data = $("#ShopPane").serialize();
    // Clear container
    $('#shopResultsContainer').html('');
    // Retrieve data from action method
    var jqxhr = $.post(url, data);
    // Handle results
    jqxhr.success(function(result) {
        //alert("ajax success");
        $('#shopResultsContainer').html(result.ViewMarkup);
    });
    jqxhr.error(function() {
        //alert("ajax error");
    });
    jqxhr.complete(function() {
        //alert("ajax complete");
    });

    // Show results container
    $("#shopResultsContainer").slideDown('slow');
}
```

**JQuery 3.x**

> The jqXHR.success(), jqXHR.error(), and jqXHR.complete() callback
>   methods are removed as of jQuery 3.0. You can use jqXHR.done(),
>   jqXHR.fail(), and jqXHR.always() instead.

```
var jqxhr = $.post(url, data);
// Handle results
jqxhr.done(function(result) {
    //alert("ajax success");
});
jqxhr.fail(function() {
    //alert("ajax error");
});
jqxhr.always(function() {
    //alert("ajax complete");
});
```

https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Comment: "The jqXHR.success(), jqXHR.error(), and jqXHR.complete() callback methods are removed as of jQuery 3.0." - https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Comment: Well aware. This post was from 4 years ago.

Comment: Why did you rollback my additions to your answer?

Comment: Dennis, my apologies, it was completely by mistake. I corrected it.

Comment: No problem, just had to ask to check if I did something wrong or should improve my edit. Have a nice week.

Answer (score 99):

This [jquery forum thread](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/what-should-i-use-post-vs-ajax) sums it up:

> `$.post` is a shorthand way of using `$.ajax` for POST requests, so there isn't a great deal of difference between using the two - they are both made possible using the same underlying code. `$.get` works on a similar principle.
>
> —addyosmani

In short, this:

```js
$.post( "/ajax", {"data" : json })
```

Is equivalent to the following:

```js
$.ajax({ 
  type: "POST", 
  url: "/ajax", 
  data: {"data": json} 
});
```

Answer (score 52):

The problem here is not the fact `$.ajax()` is not working, it is because you did not set the type parameter in the Ajax request and it defaults to a GET request. The data is sent via the query string for get and if your backend expects them as post parameters, it will not read them.

`$.post` is just a call with `$.ajax()`, just with the `type` set. Read the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) and you will see that `$.ajax()` defaults to a GET as I mentioned above.

If you go to the [jQuery.post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) page in the jQuery docs it shows you the $.ajax request with the type set. Again read the docs.

Answer (score 13):

Are you specifying this as the data parameter. `$.post` is just a shorthand for `$.ajax` which is expecting the following.

```
$.ajax({
    type : 'POST',
    url : url,
    data : data,
    success : success,
    dataType : dataType
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Just as a complementary, in the accepted answer, it is mentionned that "*The $.ajax method's data param does something different than the $.post method does, not sure what exactly, but there is a difference*"

please try using :

```
    { 
        ... 
        data: JSON.stringify(yourJsonData), 
        ... 
    }
```

Else the json object get's inserted in the payload as a url-encoded string.

Answer (score 0):

Using $.ajax we can make GET or POST requests.
Using $.post we can make only post request.
Using $.get we can make only get request.

```
$.ajax()    // Performs an async AJAX request
$.get()     // Loads data from a server using an AJAX HTTP GET request
$.post()    // Loads data from a server using an AJAX HTTP POST request
```

Answer (score -7):

In `$.ajax` you are able to synchronize, but it is not possible in the `$.post` function. To synchronize means that you can get the returned result.

```
var tmp;
$.ajax({
    'async': false,
    'type': "POST",
    'global': false,
    'dataType': 'html',
    'url': "Your Url",
    'data': {'type': 'data'},
    'success': function (data) {
        tmp = data;
    }
});
alert(tmp);
```

Comment: That's not true. You can get a returned result through:
`$.post ("your.php", function(data) { _reference **data** as your returned result_ })`

Comment: nagaking, this is absolute incorrect information and should not have any upvotes. $.ajax, $.post, and $.get can ALL return results.

Comment: @EdDeGagne  You cant able to get the return response outside of the post function

Comment: Async option has been deprecated from what i've seen, to get a result from the ajax call there are better ways that wont leave us with a browser that can turn out unresponsive. Like using the success callback.