# How to output "Thanks" text, instead of opening a separate URL using formmail.php

Tags: php, forms, contacts, formmail

This is [my site](http://andreaalice.com/nelsonsailing.com/#contact) that I'm working on the contact page.

I'm using formmail.php for the contact form (http://www.tectite.com/)

When the user submits the form I want it to say something like "Thank you, your message has been sent." But I want this text to be displayed on the page where the form is - NOT open a separate URL.

There is already a way to redirect to a separate page by using:

```
    <input type="hidden" name="good_url" value="http://yoursite.com/thanks.htm" />
```

However since my site is a single page scrolling site, I want to avoid navigating away.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use ajax functionality to do it

```
$.ajax({
                url: "page which you want to call on action",
                data: $( "form" ).serialize(),
                type: 'POST',
                async: false,
                success: function(responseObject) {
                   // $("#hiddendiv").show(); // OR
                   // $("#hiddendiv").html("thanks message");
                }
            });
```

Comment: `$.post()` is the shorthand. Also, it's suggested to show a "Loading" message on-screen, or users won't know what's going on when AJAX is being executed behind the scene.

Comment: I just gave an Idea of how we can go about it. Also i think @user2419684 is a programmer and he can manage how UI would appear.. check http://stackoverflow.com/a/12820123/165370

Comment: I've tried both this and @Kanantuteja solution below, but it is still displaying the default formmail page - how can I override this?

Comment: You need to provide more details (form mail page or send page ) in order to help you better

Answer (score 0):

Try this ajax

```
  $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "send.php",
          data: $(form).serialize(),
          timeout: 3000,
          success: function() {
            $("#contactForm").hide();
            $('#divContactFrm').html("<div id='divSuccessMsg'></div>");
            $('#divSuccessMsg').html("Thank you!")
            .hide()
            .fadeIn(1500, function() { $('#divSuccessMsg'); 
        });
          }
```

Comment: The last `fadeIn()` callback part looks weird. The callback function can be left empty.

Comment: Its upto you to add fadeIn() for hiding div or not, else use the above code to display thanks messgae.

Answer (score -2):

You can use Ajax as @Abhishek answered. Or do something like below.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
   //Your code for mailing
   header('location:formmail.php?message=set');
}
```

Then at the place you want to show the message

```
if(isset($message))
{
   echo "Thanks";
}
```

Comment: Huh? If the page doesn't reload, the PHP `isset()` won't check again. Also, don't forget to put an `exit()` after `header('Location: url');`. Wrong header syntax too.