# Which method is better $.ajax with type POST or $.post

Tags: jquery, ajax

I can make an ajax call with method post in two ways:

1) USING $.ajax() function

```
var request = $.ajax({
   url: "script.php",
   type: "POST",
   data: { id : menuId },
   dataType: "html"
   });
   request.done(function( msg ) {
   $( "#log" ).html( msg );
   });
   request.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
   alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
   });
```

Or SImply by

2) $.post() method

```
$.post("abc.php", {'user_id':user},
                     function(data)
                      {
                         if(data=="Success")
                             alert("Done");
                      }
         );
```

I want to know, which one shall i use and when?

Comment: Depending on what you want the are both the same. `$.ajax` can be better configured and supports more methods like `beforeSend`, `complete` etc. In your case it doesn't really matter

Comment: Strong overlap with - possibly duplicate of - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12820074/difference-between-post-and-ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use $.post if you are making simple requests and use $.ajax if you want to make a more complex request (request that handels both error and success, etc.)

Based on [Answer from jQuery forum](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/what-should-i-use-post-vs-ajax)

Comment: Please try and avoid link-only answers; they are generally frowned upon. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers

Comment: Sorry. Wont happen again. Just didn't want to steal someones answer. Will update my answer accordingly.

Comment: There's nothing stopping you summarising the link and picking out the salient points, as long as you're not breaching copyright whilst you do it; keeping that link as a "for more information see ... " makes it a useful reference for anyone after more detail.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want to do.

- Actually $.post internelly use $.ajax with type is set to POST. While $.ajax by default issues request as get. if you do not set type.
- Also $.post sets ContentType to application/json and datatype as json by default.
- If you want manually set or configure options like like ContentType, DataType, cache, beforesend and many more options then you can use $.ajax.

You can refer to 
[Jquery official documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

In short if you want to send post request and pass data as JSON then you can use $.post. $.post sets content type application/json