# Passing jquery parameters when i click on a tag

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to send via $.post a parameters when i click on a tag but when this happens, the parameters are not sent. I don't know why it's happening. I've watched several post with this features but none fixed my problem. This is the code:

Any ideas?

**script**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $( ".enlace_submenu" ).click(function( event ) {
                var id = $(this).attr('id');

                $.post("submenu.php", { name: id} );
            });
        });
</script>
```

**a tag**

```
echo"<li><a href='submenu.php?id_control=".$id_control."' class=enlace_submenu data-transition='slide' id='".$id_control."'><img src='iconos_ios_7/32/".$icono."' class='ui-li-icon'>".$nombre_control."</a></li>";
```

**submenu.php**

```
$nombre = $_POST['name'];
echo "<p>".$nombre."</p>";
```

Comment: Cannot see why this wouldn't work. Is there any other part of the code you are not sharing that would be relevant? Also, try adding `event.preventDefault()` in your handler.

Comment: Is your other jQuery working? If not, perhaps the jQuery include did not work. Otherwise can you tell us if you see any errors in the browser console?

Comment: @D4V1D No, I think. I've tried that now and before but when i click in the tag is does not redirect to the other page.

Comment: @sunny No error on the console.

Comment: @Rubén: An Ajax call does not make a redirect so that's perfectly normal. Have you checked in the console the return of the request?

Comment: @D4V1D Well, i checked the return of the request and there was a failure in a sql query. I fixed this and reloading and checking the return of the request all works correctly but doesn't show that in the html maybe it's redirectionating before the $.post was sent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are clicking on a link, it will navigate away, so the Ajax call will not be made. If you cancel the click, the Ajax call will reach the server.

```
$( ".enlace_submenu" ).click(function( event ) {
    var link = this; 
    event.preventDefault(); 
    $.post("submenu.php", { name: id} ).done(function(){
        window.location.href = link.href;
    });
});
```

Comment: When i click in the tag is does not redirect to the other page.

Comment: Well you have a race condition. Why are you posting and navigating in one click. You need to wait for the post, than navigate.

Comment: Yes, that happens now but I continue recieving the redirect before than the $.post

Comment: Could be possible that with window.location.href = link.href; I reload the page therefore I am losing the value? If I watch the return of the request it shows correctly but not in the page. Why is this possible?

Comment: You said you needed to navigate with the link, that is why I added it. Why are you making an Ajax call if you want the content that is returned? Just post a form or navigate or replace the content with the Ajax call.

Comment: yes, it's a good option, I tested and worked! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

I can see an error in your "a" tag, it should be:

```html
echo"<li><a href='submenu.php?id_control=".$id_control."' class='enlace_submenu'  data-transition='slide' id='".$id_control."'><img src='iconos_ios_7/32/".$icono."' class='ui-li-icon'>".$nombre_control."</a></li>";
```

notice the ' in the class attribute
Also you need to put e.preventDefault() in your code because is a hyperlink and you want to cancel the default behavior.

And if this doesn't work see the console log (Firebug) and write what's the exactly error that you're getting.

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use $.ajax() which works in the same way as $.post, infact in better way , like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {
       $( ".enlace_submenu" ).click(function( event ) {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');

         $.ajax({
            url: "submenu.php",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "HTML",
            async: false,
            data: {name: id}
            success: function(data) {
                  alert(data)                  
            }
        }); 
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you elaborate "*in better way*"?

Comment: How `$.ajax();` is *better* than `$.post();`? Especially when the documentation states that "*This is a shorthand Ajax function*".

Comment: Read the second para from this link, https://forum.jquery.com/topic/what-should-i-use-post-vs-ajax

Comment: You can even refer this, $,ajax() helps in syncronization, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12820074/difference-between-post-and-ajax

Comment: Sure, but as for the OP requirements, there is no need to use `$.ajax();` over `$.post();` (the OP is not trying to do synchronous call nor fetching JSON data).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89398/discussion-between-niranjan-and-d4v1d).

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code,

```
echo"<li><a href='javascript:void(0);' class=enlace_submenu data-transition='slide' id='".$id_control."'><img src='iconos_ios_7/32/".$icono."' class='ui-li-icon'>".$nombre_control."</a></li>";
```

Comment: That didn't work. When i click in the tag is does not redirect to the other page.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your intent, you want a click on the link do *two* things, send an ajax post **and** navigate to the url in the `href`.

Here is how you can do it:

JS

```
$(".enlace_submenu").click(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  if($this.hasClass("do-post")) {
    $this.removeClass("do-post");
    $.post("submenu.php", {name: this.id}, function(){
       $(".enlace_submenu").click();
    });
    return false;
  }
});
```

Markup

```
<a href="submenu.php?id_control=36" class="do-post enlace_submenu" ...
```

However, if you explain what you want to achieve, there might be an easier way to get the result.