# jQuery AJAX method and Post method

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

Is there any difference between $.post and $.ajax methods in jQuery

```
$.post("/SPA/Main/SaveEmployee", e).then({
    //code
});
```

and

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/Spa/SpaBulkUpload/Upload",
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    data: fd
}).then(function (e) {
    //Code
});
```

Comment: no, the first method is just shorthand for the second.

Comment: You might find this interesting : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12820074/difference-between-post-and-ajax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `post` method is a shorthand method for `ajax` with type of `"POST"` as stated in the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/). But, you do still need to specify everything else except the type property.

```
$.post({
    url: "/Spa/SpaBulkUpload/Upload",
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    data: fd
}).then(function (e) {
    //Code
});
```