# Send checked radio inputs to PHP using Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have some radio inputs these are not required to be checked. So I want to send only the checked ones.

Here is HTML:

```
<form>
    <h4>Q1:</h4>
    <label>answer1</label>
    <input type="radio" name="q1" value="answer1" data-id="1" class="answer">
    <label>answer2</label>
    <input type="radio" name="q1" value="answer2" data-id="2" class="answer">
    <label>answer3</label>
    <input type="radio" name="q1" value="answer3" data-id="3" class="answer">

    <h4>Q2:</h4>
    <label>answer1</label>
    <input type="radio" name="q2" value="answer1" data-id="4" class="answer">
    <label>answer2</label>
    <input type="radio" name="q2" value="answer2" data-id="5" class="answer">
    <label>answer3</label>
    <input type="radio" name="q2" value="answer3" data-id="6" class="answer">
  
    <!-- Submit -->  
    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </div>
</form>
```

jQuery:

```
//On form submit
$("form").submit(function(event){

    //Prevent page submit
    event.preventDefault();

    //Loop through checked inputs
    $('.answer:checked').each(function() {
        console.log($(this).val());
        console.log($(this).data('id'));
    });//Each

    //Ajax
    $.ajax({});

});//Submit
```

Here is a fiddle for the code: https://jsfiddle.net/tgp7rfhm/2/

So I want to send the checked inputs values with the `data-id` attribute.

I know about `$('form').serialize();`, But it won't include the data attributes.

So how to send the inputs values with `data-id` for checked inputs only?

Comment: What exactly do you want to send? Value or attribute or both perhaps? All the radios shown seem to have that attribute so it's not really clear what the issue is

Comment: I want to send both, So for example if user checks answer1, I get `answer1` + `1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `map()` to create array of objects with whatever properties you want then send that array

In php you would access the array from `$_POST('answers')`

```js
//On form submit
$("form").submit(function(event){

    //Prevent page submit
    event.preventDefault();
    
    const answers = $('.answer:checked').map(function(){
        return {id: $(this).data('id'), value: this.value}
    }).get()

    console.log(answers)

    const postData = {answers};
    
   // $.post(url, postData , callback)

});//S
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <h4>Q1:</h4>
  <label>answer1</label>
  <input type="radio" name="q1" value="answer1" data-id="1" class="answer">
  <label>answer2</label>
  <input type="radio" name="q1" value="answer2" data-id="2" class="answer">
  <label>answer3</label>
  <input type="radio" name="q1" value="answer3" data-id="3" class="answer">

  <h4>Q2:</h4>
  <label>answer1</label>
  <input type="radio" name="q2" value="answer1" data-id="4" class="answer">
  <label>answer2</label>
  <input type="radio" name="q2" value="answer2" data-id="5" class="answer">
  <label>answer3</label>
  <input type="radio" name="q2" value="answer3" data-id="6" class="answer" checked>
  
  <div>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: How to access the posted data from PHP? Or what type of data would it be? As I'm getting errors trying to parse the post data

Comment: *"getting errors"* is fairly meaningless without identifying the specific error and the code that generates the error

Comment: I had `dataType: "json"` in ajax request which cause errors. Both answers working fine. Thanks!

Comment: That tells $.ajax to expect json response from the php

Answer (score 2):

You're almost there. Just build a `data` object in the structure you like and send it to the server using [`$.post`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/). Your code might look like below:

```js
//On form submit
$("form").submit(function(event) {

  //Prevent page submit
  event.preventDefault();

  // Radio button submission data
  let data = []

  //Loop through checked inputs
  $('.answer:checked').each(function() {
    data.push({
      'name': $(this).val(),
      'value': $(this).data('id')
    })
  }); //Each

  //Ajax
  $.post(url, data).done(response => {
    console.log(response);
  });

}); //Submit
```

The data submitted to the server will have this format:

```json
[
  {
    'name': 'answer1',
    'value': 1
  },
  {
    'name': 'answer2',
    'value': 2
  }
]
```

Comment: So the post data would be json object?

Comment: Yes, basically, `$.post` is just a shorthand way of using `$.ajax` ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12820103/1814420)).