# Getting empty array in PHP script while sending form data using post method from ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am using serialize()method to form url encoded string, I tried searching every solution but nothing worked out , below is my code

```
<form id="idEditTaskForm">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control"  name="taskName" id="idTaskName" placeholder="Enter Task name" value="">
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="hidden"  name="id" id="idTask" value="" />
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="idEditTask">
        Save
    </button>
</form>
```

```
$(document).on('click', "#idEditTask", function(){
    $("#idCloseButton").click();
        $('#idEditTaskForm').submit(function(e) { // handle the submit event
            e.preventDefault();
            var formData = $(this).serialize();
            $.post({
                url: "http://localhost:8000/index.php?sFlag=saveTaskDetails",
                type: 'POST',
                data: {'formData': formData},
                contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                success:function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                    if(data == true){
                        console.log(data);
                    }
                }
            })
        })
});
```

```
<?php
    if(isset($_GET['sFlag'])){
        $sFlag = $_GET['sFlag'];
            if($sFlag == "saveTaskDetails"){
                print_r( $_POST);
                $id = $_POST['id'];
                $name = $_POST['taskName'];

                //$oCrudData = new CrudData();
                //$result = $oCrudData->saveTask($id, $name);
                //echo $result;
            }
    }
?>
```

while i am printing $_POST request data, empty array and undefined index error is displaying

Array ( )
Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\Users\Phaneeswar D\Desktop\Suman_learning_projects\crud_app\index.php on line 9

Notice: Undefined index: taskName in C:\Users\Phaneeswar D\Desktop\Suman_learning_projects\crud_app\index.php on line 10

Comment: Just write `data: formData` in the ajax options and remove the contentType option (jquery will take care of it for you). Putting a serialised string inside another property (which would then itself be encoded before sending) doesn't make any sense, and won't be parsed correctly by php. If you've studied examples of using ajax with serialised form data you won't have seen it done the way you're using it so I suggest you go back and look again carefully at any such examples - there should be plenty online

Comment: Also, why are you not even setting the form submit listener until after the submit button has been clicked? That also makes no sense and means it won't even be listening to try and submit the form via ajax when you click that button. Remove the `$(document).on('click', "#idEditTask", function(){
    $("#idCloseButton").click();
 `

Comment: Thanks a lot , I changed $.post() to $.ajax() method. it worked

Comment: You didn't also need to make the changes I've mentioned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replaced $.post() with $.ajax()

Comment: [Difference between $.post and $.ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12820074/2943403)