# Calling Django View from Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django, django-views

I'm using Ajax (along with Django) to perform some action on button click. I successfully call the javascript function but I can't call the Django view. There are no errors but the print statement in my view doesn't print...?

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('polls.views',
    url(r'^request_access/$', 'request_access',
        name='request_access'),
)
```

views.py

```
def request_access(request):
    print("DJANGO VIEW")
    if request.method == "POST":
        print("DATA: ", request.POST.get('request_data'))
        return HttpResponse(
            json.dumps(response_data),
            content_type="application/json"
        )
```

template.html

```
<button class="btn btn-green btn-sm" onclick="request_access(this)" id="{{ data }}"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Join Group</button>
```

javascript.js

```
function request_access($this){
    console.log("button clicked");
    var request_data = $this.id;
    console.log("data: " + request_data);
    $.post({
        url: "request_access/",
        data : { request_data: request_data},
        success : function(json) {
            $("#request-access").hide();
            console.log("requested access complete");
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Replace "post" with "ajax" in the code,now the print statement will work in your view.

```
function request_access($this){
    console.log("button clicked");
    var request_data = $this.id;
    console.log("data: " + request_data);
    $.ajax({
        url: "request_access/",
        data : { request_data: request_data},
        success : function(json) {
            $("#request-access").hide();
            console.log("requested access complete");
        }
    })
}
```

[Difference between $.post and $.ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12820074/difference-between-post-and-ajax)

[$.post vs $.ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7528757/post-vs-ajax)

Comment: thank you @chandu it's getting closer but the print statement isn't showing. I'm getting `500 (INTERNAL SERVER ERROR)` ?

Comment: I added `type: "POST",` and now I get `403 (FORBIDDEN)`

Comment: @steph add csrfmiddlewaretoken in your data. { <other form data>, 'csrfmiddlewaretoken':$.cookie('csrftoken'),}

Answer (score 0):

This will return null value.

views.py

```
def request_access(request):
    print("DJANGO VIEW")
    a = request.POST.get('request_data')
    print a
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(a),content_type="application/json")
```

js

```
function request_access($this){
    console.log("button clicked");
    var request_data = $this.id;
    alert(request_data);
    console.log("data: " + request_data);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: "/crm/request_access/",
        data : { 'request_data': request_data},
        success : function(json) {
            $("#request-access").hide();
            console.log("requested access complete");
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem, i.e my view no errors but my view wasn't called. 
Here is how I solved it :

I was trying to get the following url :

> url(r'users/change_rights', 'change_user_right',
>   name='change_user_right'),

But the users/change_rights url also matched another url I had registered :

> url(r'users', 'users_table', name='users_table'),

So django was just calling the first non ajax view and not returning any errors.

To fix it add a '$' at the end of the second url so it will not contain the users/change_rights:

> url(r'users$', 'users_table', name='users_table'),